# Marginal density, indicator function

Tags: calculus, probability

I'm trying to figure out how to find the marginal density for $Y$ of the following function:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } 0\le x \le2, \max(0,x-1)\le y \le \min(1,x) \\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx = \int_0^2 1 \cdot \mathbb{I}(x) \, dx$$

where I get that

$$\mathbb{I(x)}=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } 0 \le y \le x \le 2-y \le 2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

but this leads to

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx = \int_0^2 1 \cdot \mathbb{I}(x) \, dx = \int_y^{2-y} 1 \, dx = 2(1-y) \text{ for } 0\le y\le1$$

This is not the right answer though ($Y$ should be uniformly distributed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support of the $f_{X,Y}$ is a parallelogram; rearranging the inequalities yields
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if $0\leq y\leq 1$ and $y\leq x\leq y+1$}\\
0 & \text{else}\end{cases}
$$

Hence for $0\leq y\leq 1$,
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx=\int_{y}^{y+1}1\,dx=1.
$$
and $f_Y(y)=0$ for all other $y$.

From here, all that is left is to observe that this is precisely the probability density function for the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.